# If exists then quit VBS

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Please take this script into context with my question:

```
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Windows\Fonts\" & objFile.Name) Then
Wscript.Echo "Font already installed: " & objFile.Name
```

I want a VBS script to quit/exit/terminate if X file already exists.
Currently, it will instead give a message box saying "Font Already Installed" as expected.

If I remove the `Echo` I instead get a blank box, where I still have to hit OK.

I want the script to just automatically end if X already exists with 0 user input.

Is this possible? I have `wscript.quit` and `wscript.exit` but just get errors.

The full script can be found here:
http://www.cloudtec.ch/blog/tech/install-font-command-line-script-windows-7.html

So again, in context, I want XYZ fonts to install. If they're already installed I want the script to just simply terminate without the need to hit OK. The intention is to deploy fonts accross a network.

Comment: Where in that code did you use `WScript.Quit`? Please show the full code you used as well as the exact error you got (error number, message, line number).

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Windows\Fonts\" & objFile.Name) Then
  WScript.Quit
End If
```

Comment: Thank You, I had a littler more tweaking to do but eventually managed to get the script to execute properly. The only drawback is that if it for example I have 5 fonts (A,B,C,D,E) if B already existing then font A will be installed the the script terminates at B, before C, D and E.

But in reality as it's a new font this scenario is very unlikey to happen. Thanks agains ever so much